# Problems with grub and Windows boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

How to fix this issue?

[image]
<sup>**Error: file '/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found.   Press any key to continue..._**</sup>

Unable to login to Windows

```
#os-prober
/dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

#fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS240G2G0B-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     239616 228888692 228649077  109G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  228890624 230682623   1792000  875M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  230684672 278919167  48234496   23G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  278919168 466860031 187940864 89.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  466860032 468860927   2000896  977M Linux swap

Grub.cfg
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-685B-A185' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  685B-A185
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 685B-A185
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f12, but varies by vendor. Same key you used to select USB flash drive to install Ubuntu. Grub only boots working Windows. So is fast start up/hibernation still on? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Or does Windows need other repairs from a Windows repair flash drive?

Comment: yesy i can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu